# Contravariance issue in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, covariance, contravariance

Consider the following interfaces and classes:

```
interface BaseInterface { }

interface DerivedInterface extends BaseInterface { }

class BaseClass
{
    void baseFunc1( BaseInterface foo ) { }
    void baseFunc2( Collection<BaseInterface> foo ) { }
    void baseFunc3( Collection<? super DerivedInterface> foo ) { }
}

class DerivedClass extends BaseClass
{
    void derivedFunc1( DerivedInterface foo )
    {
        baseFunc1( foo ); //no problem here.
    }
    void derivedFunc2( Collection<DerivedInterface> foo )
    {
        baseFunc2( foo ); //error!
    }
    void derivedFunc3( Collection<DerivedInterface> foo )
    {
        baseFunc3( foo ); //fixed it, but the fix is unreasonable.
    }
}
```

When `derivedFunc1()` invokes `baseFunc1()` there is no problem, because `DerivedInterface` is assignable from `BaseInterface`.

But when `derivedFunc2()` invokes `baseFunc2()`, there is a problem, because `Collection<DerivedInterface>` apparently is not assignable from `Collection<BaseInterface>`.

Given my (admittedly not crystal clear) understanding of covariance and contravariance in java, the only way I can think of for fixing the problem is by declaring `baseFunc3()` as accepting a `Collection<? super DerivedInterface>`, which is assignable from `Collection<DerivedInterface>`.

Of course this is unreasonable, because the design of `BaseClass` cannot be bothered to know anything about some `DerivedInterface`, let alone put a cap on the derivation chain of `BaseInterface`.

This is a very frequently occurring issue in the kind of code I write, and the way currently handle it whenever I come across it is by adding conversion logic to the runtime.

My question: is there any nice and simple way of having `derivedFunc2` pass its `Collection<DerivedInterface>` to `baseFunc2` without making any unreasonable changes to `BaseClass` (such as adding that `baseFunc3()`) and without the expense of a runtime conversion?

EDIT:

The interface that I am using is not really the `Collection` interface, (Of course, I would not expect to be able to treat a collection of `DerivedInterface` as a collection of `BaseInterface`, because of the possibility that someone may add to that collection an object which implements `BaseInterface` but not `DerivedInterface`.)

I am using a `Predicate` interface which contains a method which accepts a `BaseInterface` as a parameter.  Objects implementing that interface never need to store the instances of `BaseInterface` that are passed to them, they only need to invoke some methods of that `BaseInterface`, but as Thomas points out, it does not make any difference.

So, since a `BaseInterface` must be passed to the Predicate.evaluate() method, declaring `baseFunc2` to accept a `<? extends BaseInterface>` will not work.

Comment: What will you be doing in `baseFunc2()`?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/java-generics-what-is-pecs

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was hoping for an answer which is applicable regardless of what I am trying to do within that function.

Comment: That's the hard part. Using wildcards, `?`, you won't be able to know the actual type, so you can't reference it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`BaseClass.baseFunc2` should accept `Collection< ? extends BaseInterface >` as its parameter.  In Java, the covariance or contravariance of a generic instance is declared at the point of its use, rather than at the class definition itself.

Why is `T` not part of the class hierarchy in your design?

```
class BaseClass< T > {
    void baseFunc1( T foo ) { }
    void baseFunc2( Collection< ? extends T > foo ) {
        // use foo in covariant fashion,
        // e.g., foo.contains( t ) 
        // can accept Collection< T >, Collection< S > (where S <: T)
    }
    void baseFunc3( Collection< ? super T > foo ) {
        // use foo in contravariant fashion,
        // e.g., foo.add( t )
        // can accept Collection< T >, Collection< S > (where S >: T)
    }
    void baseFunc4( Collection< T > foo ) {
        // use foo in invariant fashion,
        // e.g., foo.add( foo.iterator().next() )
        // can only accept Collection< T >
    }
}
```

Now you can do

```
class DerivedClass extends BaseClass< DerivedInterface > {
    void derivedFunc1( DerivedInterface foo ) {
        baseFunc1( foo );
    }
    void derivedFunc2( Collection< DerivedInterface > foo ) {
        baseFunc2( foo );
    }
    void derivedFunc3( Collection< DerivedInterface > foo ) {
        baseFunc3( foo );
    }
}
```

If you can't use `T` in `BaseClass`, you can only do

```
class DerivedClass extends BaseClass {
    void derivedFunc1( DerivedInterface foo ) {
        baseFunc1( foo );
    }
    void derivedFunc2( Collection< DerivedInterface > foo ) {
        baseFunc2( foo );
    }
    void derivedFunc3( Collection< BaseInterface > foo ) {
        baseFunc3( foo );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the 'EDIT' I added to my question.

Comment: So then, would you say that basically what it boils down to is that the problem lies with java not supporting proper variance declaration at the definition of generic classes?

Comment: That is correct.  Scala does allow it.  In your case you have to make all the clients of `Predicate< T >` objects accept `Predicate< ? super T >` for whatever `T` they are planning to pass to `evaluate`.  Such a declaration makes it clear to the compiler that the object is being used in a contravariant fashion.

Comment: Incidentally, although this could be considered a defect in the Java type system, it is more flexible than if we were forced to declare variance at class definition time.  The Java system lets you use naturally invariant objects as if they were covariant or contravariant by disabling (type-wise) the methods of the opposite variance.

Answer (score 3):

Change your method to `void baseFunc2( Collection<? extends BaseInterface> foo ) { }`.
That way you allow any collection of `BaseInterface` or derived types to be passed, even subclasses of `Collection`, e.g. `Set<DerivedInterface>`.

Just one note: because the type of the collection can now be any subtype of `BaseInterface` the compiler won't allow you to add elements to the collection.

If you need to do that, the best option would be to pass a `Collection<BaseInterface>` anyways, but if you're sure about what you're doing, you could also disable type checking by casting to `Collecion` only or use your third approach, which as you said, is not optimal from a design point of view.

Comment: +1, or, if you need to, make `baseFunc2` generic: `<T extends BaseInterface> void baseFunc2(Collection<T> foo)`.

Comment: Agreed, unless the goal of the method is to add elements to the collection. In which case this won't do.

Comment: Please see the 'EDIT' I added to my question.

Comment: @MikeNakis there's no need to edit, the same rules apply to `Predicate<...>` ;)